# Kafka back pressure in Quarkus

Tags: apache-kafka, quarkus, mutiny

I'm working on a project that needs to receive an event from GCP Pub/Sub, download file, parse and process file, and finally publish the results to the Kafka broker but I'm getting **SRMSG00034: Insufficient downstream requests to emit item**.

In my first attempt to publish to Kafka I was iterating msgList using stream but I read that Mutiny (https://quarkus.io/blog/mutiny-back-pressure/) can control the back pressure but I'm getting the same error.

In my scenario I've to publish two different lists and one of them has about 10k messages.
I read that I can control the overflow configuration with **@OnOverflow** but I prefer to maintain the default configuration unless it's necessary some change.

```
Multi.createFrom().iterable(msgList)
    .onItem().transform(item -> {
        ... some transformation ...
    })
    .onItem().invoke(emitter::send)
    .subscribe().with(
            item -> Uni.createFrom().voidItem(),
            Throwable::printStackTrace,
            () -> System.out.println("Done!")
    );
```

Could you point me to the right direction in order to solve this issue?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`emitter.send` is an async method. In your code, it ignores the outcome and `send` returns immediately. That's probably not what you want. I would recommend using a `MutinyEmitter` and do `onItem().call(emitter::send)`. In this case, you are going to wait for the message to be sent. Note that if sending the message fails, it will propagate the failure. With that, back-pressure will be applied as it will only get a new message when the previous one has been acknowledged.

If you want to send a batch of messages, use `.group().asList().of(...)`, and send all the messages from the list. However, as before, you would need to wait for the ack of all the messages. `Uni.join` will let you do that.

If you want to send messages concurrently but with a constrained concurrency use:

```
.onItem().transformToUni(m -> emitter.send(m)).merge(concurrency)
```

It will send `concurrency` messages concurrently. However, the order is not guaranteed in that case.